# Some question about IntPtr in C# , it can automatic cleaning by GC?

Tags: c#, c++, garbage-collection, intptr

I load a dll which writen in c++, in this dll ,C++ manages memory requests and releases, for example, the function: Init( ref IntPtr connectHandle) to request, Close(IntPtr connectHandle) to release;
In my code:

```
class Test
{
   public IntPtr _connectHandle;
   public Init()
   {
        cPlusPlus(ref connectHandle);
   }
   public Close()
   {
       cPlusPlus(_connectHandle);
   }
   ~Test()
   {
       Close();
   }
}
```

There are two object *Test a* and *Test b*, `b = a.Clone()`--There Clone() is deep copy. And two question worry to me.

1. When I don't use b, Is set b = null, but b had IntPtr Type, it can
   be released by GC?
2. If can, GC will release the memory which requsted by c++;

Comment: The GC is not involved at all. It has no knowledge of `IntPtr`, and doesn't know how to tell C++ to free the memory (other than it can call your finalizer, and that's it). If you clone your `Test`, you'll risk a double-free, and you need to manage this.

Comment: This should probably also implement `IDisposable`

Comment: It should use a `SafeHandle`

Comment: @canton7 you mean that a.Close() and b.Close() ,it maybe may cause double-free?

Comment: If a clone is naively cloning `_connectHandle`, yes

Comment: if i don`t use b.Close(), just set b =null, the object b's memory aways exist, It won't be cleaned up？@canton7

Comment: @canton7 In my program ,there many about Clone(),  i fear that these operations can lead to memory overflow... So  I want to confirm whether the memory space of b can be cleaned up automatically by GC

Comment: That doesn't change anything. If you just set `b = null`, at some point the GC will call the finalizer of `b`, and that will call `Close`

Comment: If you're manging native resources like this, you can't just have a naive deep `Clone()` method. It doesn't work. You either need to be smart and have a single 'owner' of the native resource, or you need to be smart and properly clone the native resource (i.e. call into C++ to allocate a new one)

Comment: @canton7When set b = null ,at same time i also set _connectHandle = IntPtr.Zero, Will it led to call Close()?

Comment: The GC will still call your finalizer at some point. In your code, that still calls `Close`, and passes in `_connectHandle`. This is very straightforward and there's nothing magic going on: I think you're over-thinking it

Comment: I got it, Thank you : )